# Find missing interior angle of an irregular quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Given:

quadrilateral $ABCD$

- $AD = BC$
- $\angle ABC = 75^\circ$
- $\angle BCA = 30^\circ$
- $\angle CAD = 50^\circ$

Find $\angle ADC$

Comment: Questions like this one are much better received if you can pinpoint where you are having difficulties.  Such as, "I understand that (this and that) but cannot see (the next step)".  This kind of info helps answer the meta-question potential problem answerers often have:  "is this a post by someone who  wants to learn, or is it from a person who wants other people to do their homework for free?".

Comment: What do you know about the sum of the interior angles of a quadrilateral?

Comment: The sum of interior angles are done by this formula. (N - 2)*180 where N is the number of sides. A quadrilateral has 360 degrees.

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand how to solve the question because I have tried everything, finding exterior angles et cetera. I understand the theory but I don't know how to apply it. Does that answer your question? BTW, I am not such a person who gets homework done for free and you have no right to accuse me so.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Draw a figure. Divide the quadrilateral into two non-overlapping triangles diagonally. Do you know the sum of angles in a triangle? Can you use this to find the missing angle?